# Reference request - Probabilistic interpretation of Dirichlet Laplacian eigenfunction

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations

Background: consider some uniformly elliptic differential operator
$$L=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^{m}b_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
on a bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is the diffusion with infinitesmial generator $L$. Then, under suitable assumptions on the coefficient functions $a_{ij}$ and $b_i$, the solution to the PDE
$$\begin{cases}Lu=0&\text{ on }\Omega\\u=f &\text{ on }\partial \Omega\end{cases}$$
is given by $u(x)=\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_{\tau})]$, where $\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t\notin \Omega\}$.

Then my question is as follows: consider the principal Dirichlet Laplacian eigenfunction  $\phi_{\Omega}$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$. In other words, $\phi_{\Omega}:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is the unique (up to scalar multiple) function such that
$$\begin{cases}-\Delta \phi_{\Omega}=\lambda_{\Omega}\phi_{\Omega}& \text{ on }\Omega\\ \phi_{\Omega}=0\text{ on }\partial \Omega\\ \phi_{\Omega}>0\text{ on }\Omega.\end{cases} $$
Is there some formula expressing $\phi_{\Omega}$ in terms of the expectation of some process? To the best of my knowledge, representation formulas exist only for operators of the form $L+c$ where $c\leq 0$ is a nonpositive constant, but here $\lambda_U>0$.

Of course, at the risk of stating the obvious, it is hopeless to express $\phi_{\Omega}=\mathbb{E}[f(X_{\tau})]$, where $f:\partial\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is the zero function, as that would imply $\phi_{\Omega}\equiv 0$.

I would appreciate pointers to any kind of "probabilistic formula" for $\phi_U$, even if not written as an expectation.

(For people familiar with the topic: I am aware of the formula $p(t,x,y)=\sum e^{-\lambda_jt}\phi_j(x)\phi_j(y)$, where $p(t,x,y)$ is the transition probability of killed Brownian motion in $\Omega$, but this is not what I am looking for.)

Comment: Maybe a simpler place to start that may provide insight is in a probabilistic interpretation of $\Delta u = f$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions? Interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although we know what happens in that case already as the coefficient on the $f$ is positive, but in $\Delta \phi = -\lambda \phi$, the coefficient is negative.

Comment: I forgot my minus sign sorry

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of the generalized Laplacian is the time independent limit of (thermal) diffusion processes with prescribed density (temperature) on the boundary.

This setting implies, that any start distribution of the heat carriers evolves into the harmonic distribution for $t\to  \infty$ if any single process $X_t$ reaching the boundary is reflected by changing its temperature to the boundary value, alternatively absorbing all carriers that do not match the boundary temperature and inflating the rest to a constant particle number.

The gradient field of the harmonic distribution is the static thermal flow with described boundary values and temperature transport resistance field given by the coefficients of the Laplacian.

The central probabilistic theorem of potential theory trivializing the scheme is the fact, that the distributional kernel of the Laplacian in euclidean $\mathbb R^n$ is the expected time to hit a sphere of radius x starting at the origin at $t=0$,  e.g. the Coulomb kernel $r \to  r^-1$

$$-\Delta \Phi = -r^{-2} \partial_r \left( r^2 \ \partial_r  \Phi \right) = 0  $$

is the expected time to leave the sphere of radius $r$ for the first time.